# MySQL: SELECT from three tables?

Tags: mysql

I have problems with a MySQL query with three tables. I would like to search for a name and get all (even better only the first one) phonenumber and email. Here are my tables:

```
Table 1, contact
==========
id | name
==========
1  | stefan
2  | michael
3  | andy
4  | bob

Table 2, phone
==============================
id | contact_id | phonenumber
==============================
1  | 1          | +1 434 434232
2  | 1          | +1 434 24234
3  | 2          | +1 89234
4  | 4          | +1 345345
5  | 4          | +1 434 7567567

Table 3, email
===============================
id | contact_id | emailaddress
===============================
1  | 1          | stefan@home.com
2  | 1          | stefan@work.com
3  | 1          | stefan@mars.com
4  | 4          | bob@anywhere.com
5  | 2          | michael@nothing.com
```

And this is my query, which seams to send MySQL to nirvana:

```
SELECT c.name, p.phonenumber, e.emailaddress
FROM contact AS c
JOIN phonenumber AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
JOIN email AS e ON c.id = e.contact_id
WHERE c.name = 'michael'
```

When I do only one join this works fine as:

```
SELECT c.name, p.phonenumber
FROM contact AS c
JOIN phonenumber AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
WHERE c.name = 'michael'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: You aliased email as 'a' but you used 'e' in e.contact_id.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, I have changed it, but the problem in general exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "send MySQL to nirvana"?  Do you get an error?  Does it take forever to execute?  Do you not get any results?  Please be specific.

Comment: Also, you are using 'phonenumber' when the table name should be 'phone'

Comment: Yes, it takes forever, so I get no result.

Comment: You should edit your question to say that the query is taking forever.  Otherwise we do not know how to help you.  Try running an explain (type "EXPLAIN" before your SELECT statement and run) on your query and posting the results in your question.  That will give others a way to help you optimize your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.name, p.phonenumber, e.emailaddress
FROM name_of_your_schema.contact AS c
JOIN name_of_your_schema.phone AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
JOIN name_of_your_schema.email AS e ON c.id = e.contact_id
WHERE c.name = 'stefan'
LIMIT 1;
```

Tom L.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you, I will check this also, but now I go to bed, it's midnight here. Take care, Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT c.name, p.phonenumber, e.emailaddress
FROM contact c
INNER JOIN phone p ON c.id = p.contact_id
INNER JOIN email e ON p.contact_id = e.contact_id
WHERE c.name = 'michael'
```

Comment: Hi Emanuel, thank you very very much, this was my fault, your try works perfect. Have you also an idea, how to get only one result, when a contact has more than one phonenumber or emailaddress. Thanks again.

Comment: add LIMIT 0,1 at the end

Comment: That would give you the first row of all rows matching criteria. I may have misunderstood "one result" however.

Comment: Hi ptrk, good idea, but I don't want just one result in total, e.g. I search for c.name ='%a%', I want all names stefan, michael and andy, but only one of them and not doubles/triples with all phonenummber/emailaddresses.

Answer (score 0):

To get just one result per contact, you might use aggregation in a bit unorthodox way. I modified @Emanuel Saringan's query:

```
SELECT c.name, min(p.phonenumber), min(e.emailaddress)
FROM contact c
left JOIN phone p ON c.id = p.contact_id
left JOIN emailaddress e ON c.id = e.contact_id
WHERE c.name = 'michael'
GROUP BY c.id
```

See it work here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a8700/2

Comment: Hi ptrk, thanks, but this gets me a MySQL timeout again and no result, hm?

Comment: Please test now, also compare with the sqlFiddle. Note I replaced INNER JOINS with LEFT JOINS so you get the contacts that have either phone or email (not necessarily both).